# python-OpenCV cv2.videocapture window shrinks

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspicam, opencv

I am trying to get a simple opencv-python video capture to work which shows the live stream of the camera however when i run the code the camera window frame opens up and then immediately shrinks into a tiny line. here is a picture to show:

[image: The White line in the top right hand corner is meant to be the camera window]

The white line in the top right hand corner is meant to be the frame window.

I have tried installing the V4L2 driver and the red light comes on on the pi cam but I am not able to view through the window.

any help would be greatly appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that I should of done:

> cv2.imshow('frame', frame)